SQL : creating query to add reducing totals
I have following two tables.
Table #1



ID
Amount




1
5000


2
3000


3
4000



Table #2



PO_ID
PO
Sequence
PO_Amount




1
PO1
1
2000


2
PO2
2
4000



I want to join these 2 tables in such a way that PO amount from Table2 will utilized in Table1 Amount column. eg. as shown below.
PO_Alloc_Amount and PO_Remaining_Amount will be calculated columns



ID
Amount
PO
PO_Amount
PO_Alloc_Amount
PO_Remaining_Amount




1
5000
PO1
2000
2000
0


1
5000
PO2
4000
3000
1000


2
3000
PO2
4000
1000
0


3
4000
null
null
null
null



eg. in Table1 for ID 1, the amount is 5000. So, to adjust against this amount, 2000 will be taken from PO1 and 3000 will be taken from PO2 (from Table2). These amounts will be displayed in PO_Alloc_Amount column.
After this, PO2 will have 1000 amount which will be utilized against ID 2 from Table1. ID 3 will show null value since there will be no PO value to be utilized against it.
Please let me know if you need more information.
I am expecting output query to resolve my problem

please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Does the expected result really match the given table data? I can't figure out how it could.

this really should be done in an programming language like c# python or php any other would also do

Imagine each of the sets of values as stacked bar charts. The relevant portions are where  pairs of amounts from each side are overlapping. The allocation amount can then be visualized as the narrowest band in common:
with t1 as (
    select *, sum(Amount) over (order by ID) as totalAmount
    from Table1
), t2 as (
    select *, sum(PO_Amount) over (order by Sequence) as totalPO_Amount
    from Table2
)
select *,
    least(totalAmount, totalPO_Amount)
      - greatest(totalAmount - Amount, totalPO_Amount - PO_Amount) as PO_Alloc_Amount,
    totalPO_Amount - least(totalAmount, totalPO_Amount) as PO_Remaining_Amount
from t1 left outer join t2
    on t1.totalAmount  > t2.totalPO_Amount - t2.PO_Amount
   and t1.totalAmount <= t2.totalPO_Amount + t1.Amount
order by ID, PO_ID;

https://dbfiddle.uk/n4apR5gY

Thank you very much. Above solution worked for me. I am not using 2022 so I used case condition for least and greatest functions.

I wondered about that. Great job fixing it up.
